# Loading CSV values to a Ruby class

Tags: ruby, class, csv

I'm new to Ruby, just learning to use it since last night. As my first task I set for myself, I'd like to load a CSV file to an array of Car objects I created.

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :year, :make, :model, :length

  def initializer(year, make, model, length)
    @year = year
    @make = make
    @model = model
    @length = length
  end

  def to_s
    "Year: #{@year} | Make: #{@make} | Model: #{@model} | Length: #{@length}"
  end
end

require 'csv'

data = CSV.read('/home/stapiagutierrez/Desktop/Pickaxe/cars.csv')
puts data[1]
```

How can I iterate through the data collection and load each row of values into a new Car object? Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: That should be `def initialize`, no "r".

Comment: @echoback: Hehe good catch! Still getting to grips with this beautiful language.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each car is on it's own line:

```
path = '/home/stapiagutierrez/Desktop/Pickaxe/cars.csv'
cars = CSV.read(path).collect{ |row| Car.new *row }
```

The `*` in `*row` is a ["splat" operator](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html#UC), which tells Ruby to take an array and turn it into individual arguments. It can do the opposite and turn multiple arguments into an array, as well; see Programming Ruby on [Variable-Length Argument Lists](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html#UA).

Comment: When using your code, I get this error: AccountingSystem.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected tSTAR, expecting kEND
  cars << Car.new *row
                   ^
AccountingSystem.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
puts data[1]
            ^

Comment: Works for me on 1.9.2-p0 and 1.8.7-p330. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, harbichidian, for completing this great example of processing a CSV file; but can you show what the syntax would be for iterating over each line, i.e. doing some processing on each line in a loop? This compact Ruby syntax is rather cryptic...elegant, but cryptic...